# Why bootstrap 3 row not extending to fit the content?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-push-3 col-sm-6 text-center wrapper">
            <div class="col-sm-4 inner-wrapper">
                <span class="text-center circle">A</span>
                <p class="text-center center-block">Click Start Now</p>
                <a href="" class="text-center center-block start-now">Start Now</a>
            </div> <!-- col-sm-4 -->
        </div> <!-- col-sm-6  -->
    </div> <!-- row -->  
</div> <!-- container-fluid -->
```

There will be another 2 elements with `col-sm-4` inside `col-sm-6`.

And the following CSS:

```
.container-fluid{
    margin:10% auto
 }

.wrapper{
    color: #fff;
}

.inner-wrapper{
    background-color: #ccc
}

.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #d1cfc8;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5% 15%;
    font-size: 300%;
 }

.start-now{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #96d0f1
}
```

Here is a fiddle to show the code live with Boostrap: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/93303/

As you see the circle is exceeding the `row` and it's not fitting the content, And the circle extended behind the `<p>` beneath it.

What is the problem? Can't I increase the `margin` to that limit? Is the pseudo element before `row` causing that?

Comment: the `row` usually always fits the container 100%. Now the thing is that you need a size of **12** of the columns to fit the row space. Plus you are specifying only `col-sm` which is for mobile. For desktop/laptop you need to use `col-md` or `col-lg`.

Comment: @ZombieChowder bootstrap is mobile first meaning if you specify `col-sm`, it will propagate up to `col-md` and `col-lg`. You are right on the money with the sum of columns need to be 12.

Comment: @ZombieChowder, I mean the height not the width, `col-sm-4` will work on small,medium and large screens

Comment: @Dan yeah but the total **value** of columns must be `12` and you currently have only one which is `4`. Meaning that you should add other columns so that the value is `12`...

Comment: If you want insert col inside col you must use another row.
`.row > .col-sm-4 > .row > .col-sm-4`

Comment: @ZombieChowder, I know that the element is taking only 4 columns, I mentioned in the description that there will be 2 other elements each will take 4 columns, So  at the end there will be 3 elements taking the 12 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the circle is spilling out of the top of the container because it is a span and has a display of inline by default, so the height of the element isn't properly recognized in the document flow. Just add `display:inline-block` to the `.circle` element and it will fix the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/nma51kve/

Comment: Yest that's exactly what I want, Thanks!